# Удаление элементов из state по таймеру

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Идея такая: есть локальный state (hook), в нем массив из четырех элементов. На экране есть кнопка добавления нового элемента в этот массив. При загрузке компонента в useEffect вызывается метод, который каждые 5 секунд удаляет первый элемент из стэйта. Если не трогать кнопку, которая добавляет новый элемент в стэйт, то все работает замечательно. Но если начать добавлять элементы, то удаление срабатывает по предыдущему стэйту, только потом отображается стэйт с новым элементом. Подскажите, как это исправить, чтоб все работало стабильно. Я понимаю, что нужно искать в направлении жизненного цикла, происходит конфликт состояний, но решения найти не могу.

```
const Component = () => {

    const [arr, setArr] = useState(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("render");
        setTimeout(deleteElementFromArr, 5000)
    });

    const addNewElementToArr = () => {
        let temp = arr.slice();
        temp.push('newElement');
        setArr(temp);
    };

    const deleteElementFromArr = () => {
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            console.log(arr);
            let temp = arr.slice();
            temp.splice(0, 1);
            setArr(temp)

        }
    };

    return (<div>
        <div>
            <Button onClick={addNewElementToArr}>add</Button>
        </div>
        <div style={{margiTop: '10px'}}>
            {arr.map(a => `${a} `)}
        </div>
    </div>)
};
```

https://codepen.io/slava4ka/pen/WNNvrPV

Answer (score 0):

```
const Button = ReactBootstrap.Button
const useState = React.useState

const Component = () => {

    const [arr, setArr] = useState(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']);
   const [timerId, setTimerId] = useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
       clearTimeout(timerId)

        setTimerId(setTimeout(() => deleteElementFromArr(arr), 1000))
    },[arr]);

    const addNewElementToArr = () => {
        setArr([...arr, 'newElement']);
    };

    const deleteElementFromArr = (arr) => {
        if (arr.length) {
            setArr(arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1))

        }
    };

    return (<div>
        <div>
            <Button onClick={addNewElementToArr}>add</Button>
        </div>
        <div style={{margiTop: '10px'}}>
            {arr.map(a => `${a} `)}
        </div>
    </div>)
};


ReactDOM.render(
    <Component/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```